# HTML & REST (dynamic "id" in a link)

Tags: html

I am using an HTML as a REST client. I need to send form data to a server.
On a server side (implemented with java), a path to my POST(i`m using POST to update my table) method is something like : @Path("http://www.something.com/{id}")
The path works fine, I have tested it with Postman and browser, but for my HTML client, I need the {id} part of 
my link to be dynamic.
For example, I click on some product (lets assume, I have web page with some kind of products), the browser opens a new window, so I can update a information 
about that product. To make an update, I need that product "id" to be in my link as follows : http://www.something.com/{id}

```
<form action="http://www.something.com/2" method="post">
        <input name="id" type="hidden">
        <input name="product_name">
        <input name="product_size">
        <input name="product_number">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

In the example, I just 'hardcoded' {id} to be equal to 2, and it works!
But how can I make http://www.something.com/{id} <-- this {id} part to be dynamic(in my index.html file)?

Comment: You can make HTTP requests in JavaScript; using jQuery (or simply using XMLHttpRequest).  I find jQuery a bit easier.  For example `$.post()...` allows you to post to any URL you like.  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/  ... Alternatively, you should be able to use JavaScript to programmatically alter the `action` attribute of your form, although this is not a particularly scalable approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do two things

1. Give your form an id and name, for example

> `<form action="" method="post" name="my-form" id="my-form">`

2. Write some JavaScript which sets the form's action dynamically on some action being performed, such as

> ```
> document.getElementById("my-form").action = "http://www.something.com/"+myvar;
> ```

But in my opinion I think you would be better off using JavaScript to do the post directly, rather than try changing form actions.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You for Your answers and special thanks to @Toby whose proposed solution worked! I`ll share my final solution in case some one runs in the same issue:

```
...
<body onload="getId('id')">
    <div>
      <form action="http://www.something.com/{id}" method="post" id="productForm">
        <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id">
        <input name="product_name">
        <input name="product_size">
        <input name="product_number">
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
      </form>
    </div>              
    <script>
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var id = null;

        function getId (variable){
            var idArr = query.split("=");
            id = idArr[1];          
            document.getElementById("productForm").action="http://www.something.com/"+id;
            document.getElementById("id").value=id;
        }
    </script>       
</body>
...
```

my java class with REST paths looks similar to this:

```
/**
 * to access:
 * http://www.something.com/{id}
 * @param id
 * @param product_name
 * @param product_size
 * @param product_number
 */
@Path("/{id}")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void tableUpdate(@FormParam("id") int id,@FormParam ("product_name") String name, @FormParam ("product_size") String size, @FormParam ("product_number") String number){
    ...
}
```